# When I call an async pipe in an element to be iterated, will it be created a single shared subscription or multiple?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Got a quick question about how Angular handles async pipes: given the following block of code, if I were to call a function inside an element that will be rendered N times and pass it the value of an observable as a parameter using an async pipe, will the subscription that's passed to these function executions be shared or will these be independent subscriptions?

```
<ng-container *ngFor="...">
  <div>{{ getSomeValue(myObservable$ | async) }}</div>
</ng-container>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Each async piping will result in a new subscription.
Therefore to avoid unnecessary subscriptions, you can use the `*ngIf` approch

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(myObservable$ | async) as myValue">
    <ng-container *ngFor="...">
       <div>{{ getSomeValue(myValue) }}</div>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

`myObservable$ | async` will evaluate and bind to the value of `myValue`, then it is available to use without further subscription within the template sub-tree.

Comment: I think it's not recommended to make a function call inside the HTML template, you can assign the execution result in variable and make the binding inside your template

Comment: It is not recommended. On my opinion that function call was not relevant to the question on async pipe and subscription, therefore I did not address this. There are techniques to avoid that, depends on the usecase.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the normal answer, **DON'T CALL METHODS WITH ASYNC VALUES**

Every time a change detection happens it will subscribe and unsubscribe to all of the observables again and again.
You either use noam's answer or you can try mapping the list if need be

```
public list$ = this.myObservable.pipe(map(obsValue => this.array.map(row => this.getSomeValue(obsValue)));
```

This would be much better performance wise because otherwise angular calls your getSomeValue 10 times a second.

Comment: While it's a decent argument performance wise, as far as I know - Angular handles subscriptions appropriately. i.e. subscriptions are unsubscribed when they're no longer in use. So the number of *active* subscriptions you have will not grow.

Comment: I think you are right and I edited that part. Thanks for the note